# How to send function keystrokes in Lua

Tags: windows, lua, autohotkey, logitech-gaming-software

I'm trying to write a script in G-Hub(Lua) that lets me use AHK for macroing options from my Logitech G305(specifically trying to replicate Logitech Options' Gesture Button functionality.) The code currently triggers different functions based on what mouse actions I do. I would like to send extended function keys(F13-F24) so that AHK can pick those up and execute the macros. After a lot of googling, I can't find any easy way to emulate keystrokes in Lua. G-Hub consistently gives [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGvnQ.png) regardless of what I try (keypress(), sendKey(), sendKeyDown(), etc)

TL;DR, How do I send F13-F24 in Lua.

Comment: Does this help https://gist.github.com/ewauq/2702c6b2342517a0ec9206fa101d3d7c ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It throws the same error as my attached image, except with "keypress" being "PressKey". As far as I can tell, PressKey isn't a function.

Comment: `PressAndReleaseKey("F13")`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Sadly no. Still throws that same error as the above image.

Comment: That error about "global keypress" is because you are using "keypress" - this function does not exist in GHUB Lua.  Remove the line with "keypress".

Comment: I meant the same error, but with "keypress" being replaced with "PressAndReleaseKey". My bad for not specifying.